# How can i show US county using HighCharts in my web page

Tags: highcharts

How can i show "US county" map in a web page. I see HighCharts shows the US states in the following link http://www.highcharts.com/studies/us-map.htm

I want to show US county. Is there any way to show US county. What data i should provide to highchart to render US county map.

Your help will be appreciated greatly

Thanks

Comment: You need to parse a blank svg map of the US then. Just google for it and you'll find a lot of free blank svg maps. And you'll need the Highcharts Data plugin to do the parsing magic.

Answer (score 0):

Simple iframe:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.highcharts.com/studies/us-map.htm"></iframe>
```

Then simply inspect the element's height, width, padding etc. and give your iframe approx. the same size.

```css
iframe {
  width: 820px;
  height: 550px;
}
```

Alternatively you can copy the source code, but only if you get explicit permission from the site owner.

Comment: 1) The page in question gives state level information.  OP is asking for county level.  2) loading someone else's page in an iframe as if it's your content is more sketchy than swiping the source code ;)

Comment: Oops, in that case I misunderstood the question. I also thought (never done it though) that iframing a webpage was no problem as long as you have the permission to do so.